# Is there anyway with Jenkins Git plugin to set merge-strategy option to 'theirs'?

Tags: git, jenkins, merge

I'm using Jenkins with the Git Plugin.  Facts:

- I have 2 branches `develop` and `rc` with the same ancestor.
- `develop` is at commit `635d361d2005f74dd55f274bf409d43d6413d9b0`
- I'm try to merge `develop` it into `rc`
- A change has been made to a file `x.html` independently in both branches that causes a conflict when merging
- I always want `develop` changes to trump `rc` changes when conflict occurs

In the project via the git plugin, I've added an additional behavior "Merge before build" and I can set the strategy to be "recursive".

[image: Screenshot of Jenkins Git Plugin Additional Behavior Config]

This configuration generates a merge that looks like this when run:

```
 git checkout -f origin/rc
 git merge -s recursive 635d361d2005f74dd55f274bf409d43d6413d9b0
```

However, I can't seem to specify the any strategy options, so this just generates a conflict.

Specifically I'm trying to do a merge accept theirs on conflict like below:

```
  git checkout -f origin/rc
  git merge -s recursive  --strategy-option theirs 635d361d2005f74dd55f274bf409d43d6413d9b0
```

Can this be achieved with the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to set a merge-strategy option using the Jenkins Git plugin. What I did as a workaround was to delete the additional behavior "Merge before build". Then on the "Build" phase add a build step "Execute shell" and call the commands you were trying to execute.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately as of now this seems to be the only way to make it work.

Comment: where is the SHA coming from? How do you dynamically include that in your script? What does your Shell script look like?